# Discord.py Rewrite - How can I get a user's permissions as a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, discord.py

NOTE: This post gets both Discord.py and Discord.py-Rewrite tags, as Discord.py Rewrite has been officially released and "replaced" the async version.

========================================================

I'm trying to make my own Help Formatter for my Discord Bots (a Help Formatter that will have multi-language support), but I need a way to get a user's permissions **IN** the help command, **not at the beginning**

What I'm doing in my Help Formatter is opening files and reading X line for X thing to print on Discord. It works perfectly, but I want to restrict this, because someone could see an "admin command" (if I put one) by doing the help command for the admin command. So what I would do is to put at the end of each file the permission(s) required to see the command.

On the bot side, I would the bot to get the user's perms as a *list* with all permissions the user has, not with permission IDs, but permission names, like `manage_message` or `ban_members`, things like that, so I can read this permission at the end of the file, and then see ***if this permission is in the user's permissions list***.

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You make your own decorator that implements the same features as the normal `has_permissions` decorator, but also add these perms as a variable to the command instance.

```py
def custom_has_permissions(**perms) -> commands.check:
    async def predicate(ctx):
        # Add the perms to a variable, you can format this any way you'd want
        ctx.command.required_perms = [p.replace('_', ' ').title() for p in perms.keys()]
        # Just use the normal check
        return await commands.has_permissions(**perms).predicate(ctx)

    return commands.check(predicate)
```

Now you can use this new decorator like

```py
@custom_has_permissions(ban_members=True)
@commands.command()
async def ban(ctx, ...):
    # printing ctx.command.required_perms will give you ['Ban Members']
    ...
```

This way the command will, after being invoked, hold the vaiable `required_perms` which you can use in your subclassed helpcommand

Do note however, that it'll only hold that *after* the command was invoked.

You can do `await Command.can_run(ctx)` which will run the checks and thus 'load' the variable.

(I already answered you on Discord, but thought this might be useful for people having the same question)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some dictionary mapping permission names to lists of strings:

```
perm_command_map = {
    "manage_messages": ["Command1", "Command2"],
    "kick_members": ["Command3", "Command4"]
}
```

You can get a list of all the things the user has access to by using the [`Member.permissions_in`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.permissions_in) method to get a [`Permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#permissions) object, and then using that to determine the individual permissions (If you only care about the guild-level permissions, just use `Member.permissions`):

```
allowed_commands = []
permissions = message.author.permissions_in(message.channel)
for perm, commands in perm_command_map.items():
    if getattr(permissions, perm):
        allowed_commands.extend(commands)
```

Comment: You're missing a `.items()` in the `for` loop there.

Comment: @AKX Thanks, fixed.